# What happens when a service receives a request but has no ready pods?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check, kubernetes-service

Having a kubernetes `service` (of type `ClusterIP`) connected to a set of `pod`s, but none of them are currently ready - what will happen to the request?
Will it:

- fail eagerly
- timeout
- wait until a ready pod is available (or forever, whichever is earlier)
- something else?

Comment: What would happen if you just try and see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It will time out.**

Kube-proxy pulls out the IP addresses from healthy pods and sets as endpoints of the service (backends). Also, note that all kube-proxy does is to re-write the iptables when you create, delete or modify a service.

So, when you send a request within your network and there is no one to reply, your request will timeout.

Comment: It depends on how the pods are implemented, I'd think. If the pods are running normal kind of server-side connection logic such as `nginx`, then the pod won't be *unavailable* because nginx will usually keep accepting new TCP/HTTP connections -- and if it really has maxed out, it will explicitly reject new connections. Either way, the client will not timeout.
If the pod is running some kind of a single-connection logic (i.e., accepts a connection, process it while not accepting new connections), then a 2nd TCP connection hitting that pod will be explicitly rejected by the server's TCP layer.

Comment: that would happen if you send the request directly to the pod. if you send it to the service backing it up, it is mandatory to have ready pods. if the pod is not ready, the endpoints is not added to the service object, so the iptables rules have not been created. With no iptables rules, the request will stay in the limbo, and time out.

Comment: The *"if the pod is not ready"* in your answer refers to the `readiness + liveliness probes`. If that were the point of the original question, then you're right. However, I suspect that's not the case, and the following has never been answered on the internet.

Consider: (1) there is no or infrequent readiness probe; (2) a pod unilaterally doesn't accept new connections (maybe because of the application logic in that pod) but doesn't flag such "unreadiness" to the `service`, so the `service` doesn't know that the pod is not ready.

A new request will then end up on a "not ready" pod.