# How to know when a Kubernetes service is ready after a deployment rollout?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-deployment

I'm trying to create a deployment along with a service and then access the service **immediately** as soon as the rollout is complete:

```
> kubectl create -f my-deployment.yaml
> kubectl create -f my-service.yaml
> kubectl rollout status deployment/my-deployment --watch --timeout 10m # This usually takes ~30 seconds

deployment "my-deployment" successfully rolled out

> curl "my-service" # This happens inside a pod, so the service DNS name should be available
```

Sometimes this works, but there seems to be a race condition -- if the `curl` command happens too quickly, it seems the socket fails to connect and I get a connection timeout.

This seems like the behavior I would get if there were no ready pods, as per this question: [What happens when a service receives a request but has no ready pods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54569216/what-happens-when-a-service-receives-a-request-but-has-no-ready-pods)

I expected that the completion of the rollout meant that the service was guaranteed to be ready to go. Is this not the case? Is there some Kubernetes command to "wait" for the service to be available? (I notice that services don't have conditions, so you can't do `kubectl wait`...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To know if a service is ready you can check if an endpoints object exists with the name of the service and if that endpoint object has IPs or not. If IPs are there that means service is ready. But there is no guarantee that it will still not fail because there can be a network issue in your infrastructure.

K8s primitives that manage pods, such as Deployment, only take pod status into account for decision making, such as advancement during a rolling update.

For example, during deployment rolling update, a new pod becomes ready. On the other hand, service, network policy, and load-balancer are not yet ready for the new pod due to whatever reason (e.g. slowness in API machinery, endpoints controller, kube-proxy, iptables, or infrastructure programming). This may cause service disruption or loss of backend capacity. In extreme cases, if rolling update completes before any new replacement pod actually starts serving traffic, this will cause service outage.

Here is the [proposal](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/blob/f1a799d5f4658ed29797c1fb9ceb7a4d0f538e93/keps/sig-network/0007-pod-ready%2B%2B.md) to improve pod readiness which is motivated by the above problem.

Comment: Are you sure it only considers if the replicas are created or not? In my experience running it with the `--watch` command it seems to wait until the pod is more or less running. I know it definitely waits for the pod's persistent volume claims to be bound, for example. If you have a link for the exact behavior of it that would be helpful.

I'm familiar with the probes. In the past I've done something like `kubectl wait pod --label app=my-deployment-app --for=condition=ready`. Are you saying that waiting for the pod's "Ready" condition like this would be equivalent to the service being ready?

Comment: Err never mind about the first question. I understand that the pod isn't created yet when the PVC is still being bound. So `kubectl rollout status` waits until the replica exists, but doesn't worry about its condition being Ready or anything.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added a link. In a nutshell  pod's "Ready" condition would not be equivalent to the service being ready.

Comment: Got it -- as far as the main question being asked then, is it impossible to figure out if the service is ready using normal `kubectl` commands? (Until this proposal or something similar lands)

Comment: can you try getting service and check if endpoints are not empty

Comment: Hmm I might try that. At this point it's feeling simpler to just add retry logic when connecting to the service. Anyway, I think this pretty much answers the question so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is slightly different from what you're asking but probably it will be useful to you.
I propose using [Helm](https://helm.sh) to improve your deployment experience.

**How can it help you?**

Helm has several flags like [--wait](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#helpful-options-for-install-upgrade-rollback) that can be applied during the update. It will make sure all the resources were successfully created before moving forward.

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with Helm and it's an interesting suggestion. I don't want to introduce Helm in this scenario, but do you happen to know how Helm accomplishes this? (Given that figuring this out in K8S seems to be a not entirely solved problem--see this proposal from another answer: https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/blob/f1a799d5f4658ed29797c1fb9ceb7a4d0f538e93/keps/sig-network/0007-pod-ready%2B%2B.md)

Comment: @tom Basically the same way as `kubectl wait`, except it knows which resources it is creating, so it waits for all of them, and knows which condition is appropriate for each resource type.

Comment: @JanHudec the original question already mentions how `kubectl wait` is not sufficient for services, which don't have conditions.

Comment: @tom which means helm most likely does not wait for them either, only for the deployment or whatever starts the pods.